# Concatenate two colums in one in SQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two columns, on of them is a foreign ID, how can I concatenate them into one column?

example:

```
StateID = 1
Area = "Bronx"
```

To become:

```
New York - Bronx
```

Edit:

```
Table1 = [Address] has two columns, (ID, Name)
Table2 = [Requests] has many columns including (Area, StateID)
```

Comment: What are the names of your tables? What is the format of the lookup table?

Comment: And `StateID` is the foreign key to `Address.ID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `+` to concatenate columns:

```
SELECT a.Name + ' - ' + r.Area As StateAndArea
FROM dbo.Requests r INNER JOIN dbo.Address a
    ON r.StateID = a.ID
ORDER BY StateAndArea -- ( alias can be used in order by but not in where )
```

[+ (String Concatenation)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT StateID + ' - ' + Area AS SateArea
```